# SELECT query on multiple tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables, `foo` and `bar`:

```
+----+-----+    +----+-----+
| id | val |    | id | val |
+----+-----+    +----+-----+
|  1 | qwe |    |  1 | asd |
|  2 | rty |    |  3 | fgh |
+----+-----+    +----+-----+
```

`id` is not unique here. Not all IDs in `foo` have their equivalents in `bar` and vice versa. I need to count all rows with specific ID in both tables and present them in a new table, e.g.:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | count_foo | count_bar |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |         1 |
|  2 |         1 |         0 |
|  3 |         0 |         1 |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

I've tried `UNION SELECT`:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) AS count_foo, 0 AS count_bar FROM foo GROUP BY id
UNION SELECT id, 0, COUNT(id) FROM bar GROUP BY id;
```

But this outputs row with `id=1` twice, like

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | count_foo | count_bar |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |         0 |  <- not good
|  2 |         1 |         0 |
|  1 |         0 |         1 |  <- not good
|  3 |         0 |         1 |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

I've also tried `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(foo.id) AS count_foo, COUNT(bar.id) AS count_bar
FROM foo LEFT JOIN bar USING(id) GROUP BY id;
```

But this query ignores rows from table `bar` with ID that is missing in table `foo`:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | count_foo | count_bar |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |         1 |
|  2 |         1 |         0 |
+----+-----------+-----------+  <- can I haz `id=3`?
```

What am I missing? What would be the right query or the right manual to read?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried taking your `LEFT JOIN` statement and `UNION`-ing it with a similar statement that has a `RIGHT JOIN` instead? I'm just asking off of the top of my head as I don't have time to try it.

Comment: @Stephen this actually works too, thanks. Now I have another problem -- two solutions instead of none (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to try the following:

```
SELECT d.id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE id = d.id) count_foo,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bar WHERE id = d.id) count_bar
FROM   ((SELECT id FROM foo) UNION (SELECT id FROM bar)) d;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id int, val varchar(5));
CREATE TABLE bar (id int, val varchar(5));

INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 'qwe');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2, 'rty');
INSERT INTO bar VALUES (1, 'asf');
INSERT INTO bar VALUES (3, 'ghj');
```

Result:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+
| id   | count_foo | count_bar |
+------+-----------+-----------+
|    1 |         1 |         1 |
|    2 |         1 |         0 |
|    3 |         0 |         1 |
+------+-----------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @hudolejev: Note that I removed my [other example](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3351762/revisions) using `LEFT JOINs` because it doesn't work well when there is more than 1 count of the same `id` for either `foo` or `bar`. On the other hand, this example using correlated subqueries works fine in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for OUTER JOIN?

Comment: Yes, something joining by `OR` and opposite to `INNER JOIN` that joins by `AND`. But AFAIR `OUTER JOIN` in MySQL is used only in `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` and `RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN` constructs for some compatibility reasons. Anyway, none worked for me, results are the same as with simple `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`.